# Get a name attribute values from multiple inner elements od XML File into C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-core

In following code I want to get the **name** attribute value of all the inner elements of `<List>` which are `<InnerList>`.
The requirement is to store the attribute name values to the array in c# code.

```
<List>
  <InnerList name="abc">
    <element1></element1>
    <element2></element2>
  </InnerList>
  <InnerList name="xyz">
    <element1></element1>
    <element2></element2>    
  </InnerList >
</List>
```

The required output is:

```
output = abc, xyz
```

The Output variable should contain the values of name attribute of all `<InnerList>` elements is array format which can be displayed via foreach loop.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I've tried it using XmlDocuments but it will fetch all the data inner to that elements. and in some ways I got sing value for attribute name and not for multiple elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `XDocument`

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

var result = string.Join(", ", xdoc.Descendants("InnerList")
                                   .Select(x => x.Attribute("name").Value));
```